# Repeated checkmark in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, sections, checkmark

I have implemented a tableView with sections and chechmark in my app.
I'm facing a problem when I tap on a cell, the checkmark appears on the cell, but is repeated 12 rows later.

I think the problem come from my section, the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" function use "indexPath.row" to identify the cell, but like I have some sections, I also need to specify "IndexPath.section" to determine which cell of which section is tapped.

This is my code :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell!
    cell.textLabel?.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //Je compte le nombre de ligne dans tableArray et créer autant de cellule que de ligne
    return objectsArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return objectsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
     return objectsArray[section].sectionName
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    //On affiche le boutton pour sauvegarder les catégories
    SaveCategorie.hidden = false

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        //Si la cellule est déja cochée
        if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark
        {
            //je la décoche
            cell.accessoryType = .None 
        }
            else {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            }
    }
}
```

Trying to store the item:

```
var selectedRowNumber: NSMutableIndexSet!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell!
        cell.textLabel?.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

        cell.accessoryType = .None
        if let selectedRowNumber = self.selectedRowNumber {
            if indexPath.row == selectedRowNumber {
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            }
        }
        return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        //On affiche le boutton pour sauvegarder les catégories
        SaveCategorie.hidden = false

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            //Si la cellule est déja cochée


            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            self.selectedRowNumber.addIndex(indexPath.row)

            dump(CatChoosen)
            dump(selectedRowNumber)
        }
    }
```

But I get :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0):

TableViewCells are re-used, that's why you're seeing it again on the 12th row, that same cell has been re-used.

Save the checkmark per item in your data. Then when the cell is loaded, check if the flag is set, if so, set the checkmark. If not, keep is cleared.